# HTML Divs moving around when zooming in / out

Tags: html, css

my div's are moving around when the user zooms in and out of his browser, or reduces the size of it. The website I'm creating only looks normal when you're 100% browser zoom, which is standard.

Check for yourself at http://www.enlytn.me

Here's my code, I'm looking to make it so the div's dont move around when you zoom in and out, they maintain their respective distances between one another, they don't overlap, they remain the same size, etc. Generally what the average website has, their divs remain the same when zooming in and out of the browser.

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>


<head>
      <title>Enlytn.me</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='indexstyle03.css'/>
</head>

<body>
<script src="indexjs.js">
</script>



 <div class="banner">
  <div>
     <a href="http://enlytn.me"><p id="enlytn">e.</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form">
     <h2>Sign in</h2>
      <input name='username' placeholder='Username' type='text'/>
      <input id='pw' name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password'/>
      <div class='remember'>
      <input checked='' id='remember' name='remember' type='checkbox'/>
      <label for='remember'></label>Remember me
      </div>
      <input type='submit' value='Sign in'/>
      <a class='forgot' href='#'>Forgot your password?</a>
      <a class='reg' href='#'Register</a>
 </div>

 <div class="anon">
     <h2>Continue as Anonymous</h2>
      <input name='anonymous' type='submit' value='Anonymous' />
 </div>

 <div class="gall">
      <h2>Current Affairs</h2>
 </div>



</body>


</html>
```

And here's my CSS

```
html {
background:url(Images/Background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

html, body { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}


/*Banner font start*/
@font-face {
font-family:bannerfont;
src:url(fonts/SketchRockwell-Bold.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family:bannerfontreg;
src:url(fonts/hapole_marker.ttf);
}
/*Banner font end*/


@font-face {
font-family:loginfont;
src:url(fonts/sketchy.ttf);
}


/*Banner start*/
.banner{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
background-color:#373f42;
height:58px;


}
.banner #enlytn{
position:absolute;
color:#EEF3FF;
font-family:bannerfont;
font-size:75px;
top:-95px;
left:75px;
opacity:1;
} 


/*Banner end*/

.form {
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
right: 10%;
margin: -184px 0px 0px -155px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 20px 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.07)
}

.form h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
color:#5EBA2C;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form a {
color: #5EBA2C;
text-decoration: none;

}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
width: 250px;
padding: 25px 0px;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #5EBA2C;
outline: none;
color:#5EBA2C;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

label {
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 2px;
width: 4px;
height: 4px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #46485c;
content: "";
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
border: 3px solid #252730;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #46485c;
}

#remember:checked ~ label[for=remember] {
background: #b5cd60;
border: 3px solid #252730;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #b5cd60;
}


input[type="submit"] {
background: #b5cd60;
border: 0;
width: 250px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: #16aa56;
}

.forgot {
margin-top: 30px;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
.forgot:hover {
margin-top: 30px;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #5EBA2C;
}

.remember {
padding: 30px 0px;
font-size: 15px;
text-indent: 25px;
line-height: 15px;
font-family:sans-serif;
color: #5EBA2C;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #5EBA2C;
}

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
transition: all 0.2s linear;
transform: translate(10px, 0);
opacity: 0;
}

.anon {
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
top: 85%;
right: 10%;
margin: -184px 0px 0px -155px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 20px 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.07)
}

.anon h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
color:#5EBA2C;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gall {
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
right: 50%;
margin: -184px 0px 0px -155px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
padding: 20px 30px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.07)
}

.gall h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
color:#5EBA2C;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Thank you to any help I may recieve, I'll be eternally grateful as I feel like I cannot progress with my website's development until this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fixed pixels sizes and have your elements nt move when the canvass shrinks.  Where would they go if ther don't fit?

Instead of declaring sizes as fixed pixels set them using ems which is a relative size to the parent elelment.  1em = 100% of the parent.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: So just change the px values to em values instead and I'll be good to go?

Comment: Hi, I just changed all the values to EM and nothing has changed.